# group using invoiceId and many productname

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to group all the product names in each invoiceId for association rules each product name ends with "," and if it is the last it should ends with ";"

I have new model named as associationInvoiceProduct to get the linq output

```
public int invoiceId { get; set; }
public List<string> productNames { get; set; }
```

here is the input from database table

```
       input 

invoiceId        productName
1                   bread
1                   milk
1                   water
2                   milk 
2                   rice
3                   cake

     required output

invoiceId           productName
1                  bread,milk,water;
2                  milk,rice;
3                    cake;



List<associationInvoiceProduct> allproducts=
                (from e in db.invoiceProducts
                 group e by e.InvoiceId into g
                 select new associationInvoiceProduct
                 {
                     invoiceId = g.Key,
                     productNames = g.Select(x => x.productName + ",").ToList()

                 }).ToList();
```

with the above code I get after each product "," ,  where can I add ";" in the linq if it is the last productName and if there is only single value in productName, can we add condition inside the selectMany

Thanx in advance

Updated:-
I figured this method But it looks lengthy if any suggestion to minimize the complexity

```
         r allprod = (from inv in db.saleInvoices
                      join pro in db.invoiceProducts on inv.invoiceId 
                      equals pro.InvoiceId
                      where inv.BranchId == branchName
                      group new { pro } by pro.InvoiceId into g
                      select new
                      {
                          prod = g.Key,
                          productName = 
                g.Select(x=>x.pro.productName).ToList()}).ToList();

        List<string> namelist = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < allprod.Count(); i++)
        {
            HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>();
            string tmo = string.Empty;
            int count = allprod[i].productName.Count();
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                items.Add(allprod[i].productName[j]);                   
                tmo = string.Join(", ", items);
            }
            tmo += Environment.NewLine;
            namelist.Add(tmo);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe try the LINQ `Skip` and `Take(-1)`

Comment: This will work : productNames = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.productName)) + ";"

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your comment, I had tried to update the code as you suggested 
  productNames = (string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.productName)) + ";").ToList(), the error I am getting is cannot implicitly convert List<char> to List<string>

Comment: when I change the productNames to list<char i get the following error 
Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I do not know what wrong.  Maybe you made typo.  This works : string[] input = {"abc","def", "ghi"};
            string output = string.Join(",", input.Select(x => x)) + ";";

Comment: From your description it sounds like you want productNames to be a simple string not a List of strings and then jdweng's suggestion should work.

Comment: I had tried it but didn't work , I would want to get a linq which can group all product Names of one invoiceId in one index of the list , with "," separator,  and then the second index for the product names of the next invoice and so on